# Create a dynamic array within a class (C++)

Tags: c++, class, arraylist

I'd like to implement a class with an array. If the size of the array is being breached, I would call a resize() function. However I can't seem to code a dynamic array as a data member. Can someone guide me on how to work around this?

This is what I got so far:

```
class ArrayList
{
        public:
        ArrayList()
        {
                array[ARR_SIZE] = {0};
                space = 0;
                size = ARR_SIZE;
        }
        void insert(int place, int value)
        {
                if (place >= size)
                        cout << "Sorry, that index is not accessible" << endl;
                else
                {
                        array[place] = value;
                        space++;

                if(space == size)
                        allocate();
                }
        }
        void remove(int place)
        {
                if(place >= size)
                        cout << "Sorry, that index is not accessible" << endl;
                else
                {
                        array[place] = NULL;
                        space--;
                }

        }
        void allocate()
        {
                int* array = new int[size*2];
                size = size*2;
        }
        int usedSize()
        {
                return space;
        }
        int totalSize()
        {
                return size;
        }
        private:
        int array[ARR_SIZE];
        int space;
        int size;
};
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a `std::vector` and let it manage everything for you:

```
#include <vector>

class ArrayList
{
public:
    ArrayList()
    {
        array.reserve(ARR_SIZE);
    }

    void insert(int place, int value)
    {
        if ((place < 0) || (place > array.size()))
            std::cout << "Sorry, that index is not accessible" << std::endl;
        else
            array.insert(array.begin()+place, value);
    }

    void remove(int place)
    {
        if ((place < 0) || (place >= array.size()))
            std::cout << "Sorry, that index is not accessible" << std::endl;
        else
            array.erase(array.begin()+place);
    }

    int usedSize()
    {
        return array.size();
    }

    int totalSize()
    {
        return array.capacity();
    }

private:
    std::vector<int> array;
};
```

If you really want to manage the array memory yourself, you are doing it all wrong.  Try this instead:

```
class ArrayList
{
public:
    ArrayList()
    {
        array = new int[ARR_SIZE];
        space = 0;
        size = ARR_SIZE;
    }

    ArrayList(const ArrayList &src)
    {
        array = new int[src.size];
        space = src.space;
        size = src.size;

        for(int i = 0; i < space; ++i)
            array[i] = src.array[i]; 
    }

    ~ArrayList()
    {
        delete[] array;
    }

    void insert(int place, int value)
    {
        if ((place < 0) || (place > space))
            std::cout << "Sorry, that index is not accessible" << std::endl;
        else
        {
            if (space == size)
                allocate();

            for(int i = space-1; i > place; --i)
                array[i] = array[i-1];

            array[place] = value;
            ++space;
        }
    }

    void remove(int place)
    {
        if ((place < 0) || (place >= space))
            std::cout << "Sorry, that index is not accessible" << std::endl;
        else
        {
            for(int i = place+1; i < space; ++i)
                array[i-1] = array[i];

            --space;
        }
    }

    void allocate()
    {
        int* newarray = new int[size*2];

        for (int i = 0; i < space; ++i)
            newarray[i] = array[i];

        delete[] array;
        array = newarray;

        size *= 2;
    }

    int usedSize()
    {
        return space;
    }

    int totalSize()
    {
        return size;
    }

    ArrayList& operator=(const ArrayList &src)
    {
        int *newarray = new int[src.size];

        for(int i = 0; i < src.space; ++i)
            newarray[i] = src.array[i]; 

        delete[] array;
        array = newarray;
        space = src.space;
        size = src.size;

        return *this;
    }

private:
    int *array;
    int space;
    int size;
};
```

Comment: @DarkKunai99 Not exactly perfect.  An assignment operator is missing, plus the copy constructor won't handle failures of `new` correctly.  Goes to show you that this is not a trivial thing to get correct.

Comment: For it to catch the size change I added 
if (space == size)allocate(); 
after the space increment

Comment: @DarkKunai99 - Your class won't be able to handle this correctly: `int main() { ArrayList a1; ArrayList a2; a1=a2; }`  Once you fix that, then you will be somewhat closer to having something useful.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie: how is it not handling `new` correctly? If `new` fails it throws an exception, thus aborting the constructor.

Comment: @RemyLebeau - Ok.  I see that you allocated first before assigning the other members.

Comment: @DarkKunai99: calling `allocate()` before the space increment instead of after was intentional, no need to allocate memory until it is actually needed.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie: I added an assignment operator.

Comment: @RemyLebeau The problem with the above code is (assuming initial size 10) if [0] - [9] are filled, I cannot add anything to [10] because place > space, and the exception will throw me before being able to allocate. I would therefore have to re-add a value to one of the slots [0-9] to increment space by one.

Comment: Also if the above is worked around, we should have `if(array[place]==NULL)` before incrementing space, since adding a value to an already occupied slot will not necessarily increase space

Comment: @DarkKunai99: look at my example again more carefully. If `space==10` then `array[0]`-`array[9]` are filled, so an `insert()` at `place=10` has to call `allocate()` if `space==size` before it can then fill `array[10]`. Since you are not providing an `add()` function to the class, `insert()` has to detect when `place==space` to perform an append at the end of the array. `std::vector` allows an insert at `end()` for that same reason. Again, having `insert()` call `allocate()` before filling `array[place]` instead of after wards was intentional in my example.

Comment: @DarkKunai99: there is no need to ever check `array[place] == NULL` in this kind of code, since there are never any empty slots between `0`-`space`. Also, since NULL is 0, you would never be able to store 0 values in the array if you have the class looking for NULL values.

Answer (score 7):

Use [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector).  C++ doesn't support variable-length or dynamically-sized arrays, in classes or otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have reputation to leave you a comment yet, but have you tried C++'s `std::vector` ? It does exactly what you're looking for:

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/?kw=vector

Comment: Yeah, I'm aware that the C++ equivalent to a Java arraylist is a vector, but I was hoping to come up with an alternative implementation. Thanks though.

Comment: What's wrong with using the default `vector` implementation?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you should be using [malloc](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/malloc/) and [realloc](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/realloc/).  This should work the same as Remy's answer using new and delete.

Declare your buffer as an int* and keep track of the size with a variable that you increment.  If your size exceeds the amount of space in your dynamic array, reallocate.